# How to display all lat values from this

Tags: android, sqlite

I am retrieving latitude data from an SQLite Database.

I have a table filled with longitude and latitude values.

My query is:

```
 public Cursor fetchAllCountries() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String SelectQuery="select * from "+ TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(SelectQuery,null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

My `MainActivity.java` contains:

```
Cursor cursor = myDB.fetchAllCountries();

/* for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    double data=list.get(i);
    System.out.println(data + " ");
}*/

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        double data = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
        System.out.println(data + " ");
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: what is the question and what is the problem?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are attempting to accomplish here. You want to display the latitude where? It seems like you have code that should compile and do what you need it to. Are you asking how to display it in Android itself (because you are outputing to stdout currently.

Comment: SIr @Knossos, yes i want to access lat long values from javascript but at present i want to display it in Android itself.

Comment: Then you should search Google for a tutorial / example to Android UI development.

Comment: Sir I googled but didn't found anything, i am new to androidstudio.                 Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Cursor fetchAllCountries() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String SelectQuery="select * from "+ TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(SelectQuery,null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Cursor cursor = myDB.fetchAllCountries();

double[] array = new double[cursor.getCount()];
int i = 0;

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        double data = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
        array[i] = data;
        txt.append(Double.toString(array[i]));

        i++;
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a example.

```
private static List<Information> getAllInformation(Cursor cursor) {
    List<Information> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ID));
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_TITLE));
                String mediaName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_MEDIA_NAME));
    Information info = new Information(id, title, mediaName);
                list.add(info);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public static List< Information > getAllInformation() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return getAllInformation(cursor);
}
```

in Activity

```
List<Information> mListAll;
mListAll = YourNameTable.getAllInformation();
```

Class Information.class

```
public class Information {
int id;
String title;
String mediaName;

//get
//set

}
```

Comment: Sir I am getting an error at Information may i know what it is ,  android studio asked me add Class Information like that,Thank You

Comment: I update my answer